# How to make image inline with text

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I'm learning html and have run into some issues when trying to code my own blog page.

I'm trying to create a little section that brings you to the latest post but I'm having trouble with layout.

I want it to have the text and image cleanly floated next to each other, like so:

[image: Image cleanly floated to left of text]

Instead I'm getting the text beneath the image, like this::

[image: text below image]

I don't understand why things aren't floating properly.

Here's the relevant html:

```css
.newest {
  border: 4px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: clamp(45ch, 50%, 75ch);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img.newIcon {
  float: inline-start;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1px, 1px;
  border: #111111;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <div id="newest" class="newest">
        <img class="newicon" src="images/icons/making-a-blog.png">
        <h2>Making a Blog</h2>
        <p>This is an article I wrote about making a blog. It describes my process and experience.</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `img.newIcon` wont select `<img class="newicon">` Case matters. Furthermore, `inline-start` isn't a valid value for `float` for any browser other than Firefox. And finally, there's no comma in `margin: 1px, 1px;`

Answer (score 0):

Add float property to `newest` div and `newIcon` image. Also add margin 0 to h2 tag.

```
.newest {
   border: 4px solid #cfcfcf;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 16px;
   width: clamp(45ch, 50%, 75ch);
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   float:left;
}

img.newIcon {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   margin: 1px 5px; //removed , (comma) in two values
   border: #111111;
   float:left;
}
h2 {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kxgnjh23/1/)**

Comment: This changed nothing. The website looks exactly the same except the div is now on the left instead of centred.

Comment: You asked only about image and text side by side. Other webpage code is also not provided....

Comment: provide code above div newest, so position of newest can be defined....

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated code once:

```
.outer-box{
  border: 4px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: clamp(45ch, 50%, 75ch);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float:left;
}

.outer-box img{
 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1px 5px;
  border: #111111;
  float:left;
}
<div class="outer-box">
        <img src="images/icons/making-a-blog.png">
        <h2>Making a Blog</h2>
        <p>This is an article I wrote about making a blog. It describes my process and experience.</p>
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to learn `grid` and `grid-template`, you can speed things up.

```css
.newest {
  border: 4px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
}

img.newIcon {
  float: inline-start;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1px, 1px;
  border: #111111;
}

.newest_image{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>TEST</p>
  <div id="newest" class="newest">
      <div class="newest-image">
        <img class="newicon" src="https://hostingdunyam.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/html-nedir.png">
      </div>
      <div class="newest-info">
        <h2>Making a Blog</h2>
        <p>This is an article I wrote about making a blog. It describes my process and experience.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</html>
```